# Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.InternalTransform' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Transform'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

It happens when I am trying to show a dialog using Caliburn Micro's WindowManager.

What is weird, is that it does not happen always. Only sometimes, as if timing played a role in it, which makes no sense to me.

The exception happens in the following method in WindowManager's internal class, DialogHost:

```
    void ArrangePlacement()
        {
            maskingLayer.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var placement = new ElementPlacement
                {
                    Transform = (Transform)currentPage.TransformToVisual(null),
                    Orientation = currentPage.Orientation,
                    Size = new Size(currentPage.ActualWidth, currentPage.ActualHeight)
                };

                elementPlacementAnimator.AnimateTo(placement);
            });
        }
```

I should add that it is not [this issue](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/220), as my version of Caliburn Micro is 1.5.1, which already has this fix in it.

Comment: I ended up fixing it on my own and I posted a patch on Caliburn's board: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/352

Comment: Aaaand it is fixed in Caliburn: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/732c093335baa0cd8104700e4c38b204ab0c38d3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with Caliburn, which is now fixed.

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/732c093335baa0cd8104700e4c38b204ab0c38d3